# Erro ao gravar valor Decimal com .Net Core e MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, asp.net-core

Em meu projeto possuo um **campo Valor** do **tipo Decimal**, como configurei a **cultura para pt-br** no meu projeto preciso enviar o valor com o separador **","**. Se defino o **input** como **text** ele não aceita enviar com **","**, apenas **"."** o que no banco de dados não considera como separador monetário. 
Se defino o campo de **input** como do tipo **number** ele aceita a **","** porém não envia nem recebe ela quando recebo o retorno no edit. O que tentei foi dar um **replace** no **"."** transformando em **","** no envio, porém não objetive sucesso. Segue abaixo meus códigos, caso tenha uma maneira melhor de se trabalhar com Decimal no .net core ficarei grato se alguém puder explicar.

Exemplo: Se envio o valor 12,02 ou 12.02 ele grava no banco 1202

View:

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Valor</label>
      <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" id="valor" asp-for="Valor"/>
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditarContrato(int ContratoId, Contratos contrato)
        {
            if (ContratoId != contrato.ContratoId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var Valor = Convert.ToDecimal(contrato.Valor).ToString().Replace(".", ",");

                contrato.Valor = Convert.ToDecimal(Valor);

                await _contratosRepositorio.Atualizar(contrato);
                return RedirectToAction("Contratos");
            }

            return View(contrato);
        }
```

Model:

```
public decimal Valor { get; set; }
```

Startup:

```
// Definindo a cultura padrão: pt-BR
            var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("pt-BR") };
            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "pt-BR", uiCulture: "pt-BR"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });
```

Comment: no backend, trabalhe apenas com decimal, e mande decimal para o banco, não faça isso:: `var Valor = Convert.ToDecimal(contrato.Valor).ToString().Replace(".", ",");` Uma coisa é o valor numérico, outra é a exibição no front. Agora no front, tente usar o atributo `lang` para definir a exibição no formato pt-BR

Comment: trabalhando direto com o decimal tenho o mesmo problema de não reconhecer a "," ou ".". sobre o lang já esta definido para pt-br no HTML, porém no edit ele não me retorna o valor se o campo de input for do tipo number, apenas tipo text, já com o campo tipo text não consigo enviar se coloco "," no valor.

Comment: como o @RovannLinhalis comentou, trabalho com o valor decimal, para isso, faça o replace antes de converter, assim por exemplo: `var Valor = Convert.ToDecimal(contrato.Valor.Replace(",","."));`  se o valor tiver pontos de milhares, cifrão, etc, precisa substituir antes tbm. Para isso já tem perguntas aqui no site, só procurar

Comment: @RicardoPontual fazendo direto assim não aceita o Replace, para usar o Replace eu primeiro não preciso converter em string? Eu pesquisei bastante aqui e no google, e não achei nenhuma solução para esse problema, o melhor que consegui foi definir o idioma como "en" ai consigo gravar com o ".", porém isso me da problema em outros retornos, gostaria de deixar o idioma padrão em pt-br

Comment: no banco você sempre vai gravar com pontos, só muda isso na hora de exibir para o usuário

Comment: @RovannLinhalis o problema e que não importa se digito com "." ou "," de toda maneira ele não reconhece na hora de gravar no banco. Ao tentar o colocar var Valor = Convert.ToDecimal(contrato.Valor.Replace(",",".")); recebo o erro de que "não conseguiu resolver o símbolo de "Replace".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui encontrar um solução mais simples personalizando a cultura direto no startup. Segue a resolução caso mais alguém venha a ter esse mesmo problema:

```
 // Setting the default culture: pt-BR
    var defaultDateCulture = "pt-BR";

    // Formatter number
    var ci = new CultureInfo(defaultDateCulture);
    ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
    ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";

   // Configure the Localization middleware
   app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
   {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(ci),
        SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
             ci,
        },
        SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
             ci,
        }
        });
```